# running complex commands of bash on python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

Anyway to integrate scripts into os ?

For example I have a file called getInfo

getInfo is this file:

```
KEY=$(grep -i -e "^$1:" username.sql |sed 's/.*://')
grep -e "^$KEY" info.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

The specifics isn't important but basically it just gets the info of some username. Example in bash

```
$ ./getInfo username1
Hello
```

In python it would be

```
import os
os.system('./getInfo username1')
```

And I'll run this python file on bash

```
$ python this.py
'KEY' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in python?

Comment: Has getInfo the appropriate shebang line to run it with bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getInfo.sh should have `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.

It is recommended to use `subprocess` module for executing bash scripts/commands.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("./getInfo.sh", shell=True)
```